# LNK2019 on function that does exist in an included *.cpp file

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, linker, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

For Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 in a new project I'm getting an unexpected LNK2019 error.

I have a test function calling a function in another project where I've included the necessary `*.cpp` file into the test project so I can access the internals of a DLL for testing.

test.cpp:

```
#include "dllsubmodule.h"

void TestCountPagesInSomething()
{
    // ... setup ...
    int nPages;
    nPages = CountPagesInSomething(iCurrentPos, hashFoundPages, hashPageCounts, sFoundData);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TestCountPagesInSomething();
}
```

dllsubmodule.h

```
#pragma once

int CountPagesInSomething(
    int iCurrentPos, 
    std::map<int, ERPPageInfo>& hashFoundPages, 
    std::map<std::string, int>& hashPageCounts, 
    const wxString& sFoundData
);
```

dllsubmodule.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dllsubmodule.h"

int CountPagesInSomething(
    int iCurrentPos, 
    std::map<int, ERPPageInfo>& hashFoundPages, 
    std::map<std::string, int>& hashPageCounts, 
    const wxString& sFoundData
)
{
    // implementation code here...
}
```

For whatever reason the linker error seems to be complaining that `CountPagesInSomething()` doesn't exist.  I suspect I'm having trouble with name mangling variations but I've no idea how to diagnose the problem.

Note: `CountPagesInSomething()` is internal to the DLL and not a DLL export.

Right now this is just a console project.  I'm trying to get a basic `printf()` test working before I figure out what kind of unit test framework to use.

Comment: I probably should have included the project files used here.  *.sln, *.vcproj etc.  I guess I should either try to reproduce this so I can include missing information or just delete the question.